# eliminar todos los select de un option cargados dinamicamente

Tags: html, jquery, select

mi problema es que cree una ventana modal con bootstrap y dentro de esta un select con sus respectivos option, estos option se cargan dinamicamente a traves de una funcion en jquery, mi problema es que al cerrar el modal la informacion de los select sigue ahi y al abrir el modal nuevamente crea una segunda copia de los select y asi sucesivamente si sigo apretando el boton, pienso que lo mejor es eliminarlos cuando aprete el boton cancelar pero he probado de todo y no funciona. les dejo mi codigo.

```js
<script language="javascript">
        function inicializacion() {
            var titulo = "";
            var aSelect = [];

            var levantaModal = function (titulo, aSelect) {
                //titulo del modal
                $('#tituloModal').html(titulo);
                //llenado del combobox (select)
                $.each(aSelect, function (index, val) {
                    $('#categoria').append($('<option>', {
                        value: index,
                        text: this
                    }));                                       
                });
                $('#modalDinamicoProductos').modal("show");
            };

            var limpiarCamposSelect = function(){
                $('#categoria').empty();
            };

            $('#btnAbarrotes').click(function () {
                titulo = "Abarrotes";
                aSelect[0] = "Legumbres";
                aSelect[1] = "Pastas";
                levantaModal(titulo, aSelect);
            });           

            $('btnCancelarModal').click(function(){
                limpiarCamposSelect();
            });

        }
        inicializacion();

    </script>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
        <h5>Categoria</h5>
        <select name="producto" id="categoria">
        <!-- aca se rellenan los select -->
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
        <h5>Producto</h5>
        <select name="producto" id="producto">
            <!-- aca se rellenan los select -->
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
        <h5>Marca</h5>
        <select name="producto" id="marca">
            <!-- aca se rellenan los select -->
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agrega el resto del HTML.  El modal y el boton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace un `$('#categoria, #producto, #marca').empty();` antes de llenar el Select y listo

Comment: funciona a la perfección